# SQL Server: not like (<>) hides null values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
select * from Table1 where Table1.Name <> 'John'
```

It returns everything that has not Name = 'John' but it doesn't return null values as expected. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Add an `OR Table1.Name IS NULL` check

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Table1.Name <> 'John' 
      OR Table1.Name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because every operation with null values returns false as a result. Try

```
where IsNull(Table1.Name, '') <> 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table1 where Table1.Name is null or Table1.Name <> 'John'
```